# Selecting timestamp in Redshift extremely slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have a table that looks like the following (altough with nicer column names)

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_schema.my_table
(
    tid VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL  ENCODE RAW
    ,sid VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL  ENCODE RAW
    ,"timestamp" TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL  ENCODE RAW
    ,p VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL  ENCODE RAW
    ,vid VARCHAR(100)   ENCODE lzo
    ,wid VARCHAR(100)   ENCODE lzo
    ,aid VARCHAR(100)   ENCODE lzo
    ,v VARCHAR(512)   ENCODE lzo
    ,added TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL  ENCODE az64
    ,meta VARCHAR(512)   ENCODE lzo
    ,PRIMARY KEY (tid, sid, "timestamp", p)
)
DISTSTYLE KEY
 DISTKEY (tid)
 SORTKEY (
    tid
    , sid
    , "timestamp"
    , p
    )
;
```

After a while we got complaints that a query which loads data into an intermediate storage was very slow (~1h) when returning ~9 miljon rows.

```sql
select
  "tid",
  "sid",
  "p",
  "aid",
  "v",
  "timestamp",
  "added"
from
  "my_schema"."my.table"
where
  (
    "timestamp" >= TIMESTAMP '2021-08-03 00:00:00'
    and "timestamp" < TIMESTAMP '2021-08-13 00:00:00'
  )
  and (
    "tid" in (
      <some 25 strings>
    )
  )
```

After trying all things that made sense (running VACUUM, modifying encoding, changing distribution and sortkeys, checking that the query wasn't disk based, etc) with just minor improvements, I noticed that if I didn't select the two TIMESTAMP columns it ran in less than 2 min. But what was even stranger is that if I added them back in but as epoch values

```sql
SELECT
 ...
 extract('epoch' from "timestamp") as "timestamp",
 extract('epoch' from "added") as "added"
 ...
```

The time didn't increase but stayed under 2 min.

The number of rows returned is the same and the size of the data is just marginally smaller than if returning the timestamps normally. So how can adding a transformation that does not significantly reduce the data size still reduce the time of the query to a fraction of what it took before?

*Edit, Additional info:*

Running EXPLAIN on the query returns this

```
XN Seq Scan on sensor_measurement (cost=0.00..1063118.40 rows=265834 width=110)
Filter: (("timestamp" < '2021-07-13 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" >= '2021-07-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((tid)::text = ANY ('{...}'::text[])))
```

Info from SVL_QUERY_SUMMARY

| stm | seg | step | maxtime | avgtime | rows | bytes | rate_row | rate_byte | label | is_diskbased | workmem | is_rrscan | is_delayed_scan | rows_pre_filter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2752883853 | 1318572877 | 9940746 | 0 | 3612 | 0 | project | f | 0 | f | f | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2752883853 | 1318572877 | 9940746 | 16280 | 3612 | 5 | return | f | 0 | f | f | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 2758936210 | 2758936210 | 9940746 | 1095624724 | 3604 | 397253 | return | f | 0 | f | f | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1977 | 1576 | 50 | 1488 |  |  | hash tbl=882 | f | 10485760 | f | f | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1977 | 1576 | 50 | 888 |  |  | scan tbl=202827 name=Internal Worktable | f | 0 | f | f | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | 2758936210 | 2758936210 | 9940746 | 1394321076 | 3604 | 505555 | scan tbl=202832 name=Internal Worktable | f | 0 | f | f | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 2752883853 | 1318572877 | 9940746 | 1254676660 | 3612 | 455914 | scan tbl=101593 name=my_table | f | 0 | t | f | 20694790 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 113 | 113 | 25 | 0 |  |  | scan tbl=0 name=Internal Worktable | f | 0 | f | f | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2752883853 | 1318572877 | 9940746 | 0 | 3612 | 0 | project | f | 0 | f | f | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 113 | 113 | 25 | 444 |  |  | bcast | f | 0 | f | f | 0 |

I did not end up making any permanent changes to the table for now even if it might make sense to move timestamp so it is the first sort key and change encodings.

SVV_TABLE_INFO shows table size to be 2 330 and number of rows 26 594 918.

The table has been VACUUMED and ANALYZED.

Comment: There are a few possibilities I can see right off but instead of serially running through these we may be able to narrow things down with some more information.  Can you post the EXPLAIN plans for the 1 hr and 2 min queries.  (Actual execution reports as well if you can.)  Also how big is my_table and is it vacuumed and analyzed?  Lastly how long (number of elements) is the tid IN list (described as "some string")?

Comment: Can you also post the final table you ended up with, as you mention changing sort order and encodings.

Comment: The inital question has been edited to include the information that you want. The number of elements in the "IN" list is currently 25. I did not see a significant change if I brought it down to less than 10 as long as I kept the ones giving large amounts of data.